# Delete artifacts which are not downloaded for 6 months

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

In JFrog Artifactory, I need to delete the artifacts which are not downloaded for a period of 6 months. I have gone through the [JFrog repository](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup/artifactCleanup). It is mentioned to run via REST API, but I am not pretty sure how to use it.

How can we implement this? or if there is some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to refer to this user plugin, [artifactCleanUp plugin](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup/artifactCleanup) can be used to delete artifacts which are not downloaded for certain days/months.

Comment: @Kashif, Im checking this plugin. For execution of this plugin, We need to place the groovy, properties and json files inside var/etc/artifactory/plugins folder and we need to run the curl command. Is it the right way to do ? Im bit confused on the execution of it.

Comment: @Kivi,place the artifactCleanup.groovy and artifactCleanup.json under the <Artifactory_Home>/etc/plugins folder (/var/etc/artifactory/plugins), do not place the artifactCleanup.properties as it is deprecated. Once the artifactCleanup.groovy and artifactCleanup.json is placed correctly with correct permissions, then change the artifactCleanup.json with repo name, time unit, time interval and all and run the reload plugin rest API  https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ReloadPlugins

Comment: Once the plugin is reloaded, then run the plugin using the below curl,
curl -X POST -v -u admin:password "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/plugins/execute/cleanup?params=months=1;repos=libs-release-local;dryRun=true;paceTimeMS=2000;disablePropertiesSupport=true"

Comment: Thanks Kashif, so file level we don't need to mention the Jfrog URL and only during execution of CURL command only need to mention that ?

Comment: Yes, file-level no need to mention the JFrog URL and only pass the JFrog URL when executing the plugin using the curl.

Comment: Thank you so much Kashif, it worked for me. One last question, can we use a comma and add more than 1 repository to delete at a time ? or do we need to use curl command separately for other repositories ?

Comment: Kivi, AFAIK, in the curl command only one repository needs to be passed, however, if you are using the artifactCleanup.json file then you can pass multiple repositories separated by a comma and then just run the plugin using the same curl as below $curl -X POST -v -u admin:password "http://localhost:8080/artifactory/api/plugins/execute/cleanup"

Comment: @Kashif, I am getting success by the curl command and my logs are getting updated if I run the command in local. If I execute my commands through Jenkins job, my build is getting success and my log file in server is not getting updated. Any specific reason or do we need to provide some configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use the [delete](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DeletingFiles) command of the JFrog CLI.

The command accepts a [file spec](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-Search,Set-PropsandDeleteCommandsSpecSchema).

Write an AQL query with [Relative Time Operators](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-RelativeTimeOperators), and pass it in the `aql` field of the file spec.

Comment: Jfrog CLI has to be done manually right ? I have this scenario to be done automatically, can we use Jfrog CLI to run daily night some fixed time ? Kindly provide your inputs.

Comment: You can use Jfrog CLI in a script, all of its commands can be executed non-interactively. Set env var CI=true to disable all interactive procedures. Write a script or use a CI server to run on a schedule.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I was supposed to use the artifactCleanUp plugin. Can you provide your inputs on the same please ?